# Need help understanding USACO solution

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops

I was trying to solve the Broken Necklace problem from USACO and I came across this solution.  The problem statement is here: https://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?S=beads&a=c3sjno1crwH

I am confused why the person who wrote this solution made 3 copies of the initial string, and basically the entire for loop.

I have tried looking for other solutions online that might explain it better, but there is a small number of python solutions to this problem and many of them are completely different.

```
'''
ID: krishpa2
LANG: PYTHON3
TASK: beads
'''



with open('beads.in','r') as fin:
    N = int(fin.readline())
    beads = fin.readline()[:-1]

def canCollect(s):
    return not ('r' in s and 'b' in s)

beads = beads*3
max = 0

for p in range(N, N*2):
    i = p-1
    left = []
    while i > 0:
        if canCollect(left + [beads[i]]):
            left.append(beads[i])
            i -= 1
        else:
            break

    i = p
    right = []
    while i < 3*N - 1:
        if canCollect(right + [beads[i]]):
            right.append(beads[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            break

    result = len(left) + len(right)
    if result >= N:
        max = N
        break
    elif result > max:
        max = result
print(max)
with open('beads.out','w') as fout:
    fout.write(str(max) + '\n')
```

The program is correctly working, I just wanted to know why.

Comment: Try copy-pating your code in [this visualizer](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) and see the code run step-by-step for yourself. Would be better from what anyone can explain here...

Comment: hereis solution [broken necklace](https://github.com/darrencheng0817/AlgorithmLearning/blob/e6f2fec8f1a5e6041cbeb52970db96a261ee798f/USACO/section1/beads/beads.py)  in simple word you need to find the frequency of each beads consecutively ie how many of same color bead are togther, take 2 color frequency at a time, the two which sum is large is your solution

Comment: @prashantrana I looked at that solution, but it fails the USACO grader if the beads = "rrr". EDIT: I added a clause where if the beads == beads[::-1], it returns the length of the beads. I submitted that solution and it passes the USACO grader.

Comment: Cool, congrats, for any problem you can look into GitHub for code solution

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question is pretty old, but I still want to answer it for future people, so I have made a fully commented version below (based on [this](https://github.com/jadeGeist/USACO/blob/master/1.2.4-beads.py) answer by joshjq91) -

```
"""
PROG: beads
LANG: PYTHON3
#FILE
"""

# Original file from Github by joshjq91 
# (https://github.com/jadeGeist/USACO/blob/master/1.2.4-beads.py)
# Comments by Ayush

with open('beads.in','r') as filein:
    N = int(filein.readline()) # Number of beads
    beads = filein.readline()[:-1] # Necklace

def canCollect(s):
    return not ('r' in s and 'b' in s) # If r and b are not in the same str,
                                       # then you can collect the string.
beads = beads*3 # Wraparound - r actually can be shown as r r r (wraparound 
                # for the front and back)
max = 0 # The final result

for p in range(N, N*2): # Loop through the 2nd bead string (so you can use
    i = p-1             # wraparounds for the front and back)
    left = []
    while i > 0: # Check if you can collect beads (left)
        if canCollect(left + [beads[i]]): # Can colleect
            left.append(beads[i]) # Add to left
            i -= 1 # Loop through again
        else:
            break # Cannot collect more beads - break

    i = p # You will otherwise have a duplicate bead (left is i=p-1)
    right = []
    while i < 3*N - 1:        # Check if you can collect beads (right) - i has
        #print("righti",i-N)  # to be less than 3*N - 1 b/c that is the length
        # ^ for testing       # of the beads + runarounds.

        if canCollect(right + [beads[i]]): # Can collect
            right.append(beads[i]) # Add to right
            i+=1 # Loop through again
        else:
            break # Cannot collect more beads - break

    result = len(left) + len(right) # Final result
    if result >= N: # The result was greater than N means that the whole
        max = N     # necklace is the same (EX: rwr)
        break # Break - we now know we don't need to go through again b/c the
              # whole string is the same! 
    elif result > max: # The result makes sense
        max = result

with open('beads.out','w') as fileout:
    fileout.write(str(max) + '\n') # Final result
```